# How to integrate Intel C++ compiler 2015 with fresh installation of Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have installed Visual Studio 2013 first and then Intel Parallel Studio 2015 afterwards.
The options for Intel parallel studio was showing in the Visual Studio 2013(right click project in VS 2013).
I had problems with Visual studio 2013 and Intel C++ compiler integration,
since VS 2013 is not officially supported by Intel C++ 2015.
I have uninstalled VS 2013.

Now I installed Visual Studio **2012** and I find no Intel parallel studio options in the project right click menu in Visual Studio 2012.

Should I uninstall and reinstall Intel Parallel studio 2015 to get it detected by VS 2012.
Or any methods are there to detect Intel parallel studio 2015 by VS 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Intel C++ 2015 include only x64 version, so
in the project property, change the Platform to x64, then General->Platform ToolSet to Intel C++ Compiler XE 15.0

Answer (score 1):

You should reinstall Intel Parallel studio as the installer will configure the necesary modules for Visual Studio 2012 if it is available at the time.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: did you read my answer? it sounds like an auto comment your response.